# Bounding an integral from below... singularity.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, logarithms

Let $f$ be a  probability density function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, is there a way to bound the following integral from below (for $\textit{any small enough}$ $h$) ?

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} \Big(\frac{|x|^2}{h} +|y|^2+h\log(f(x,y))\Big)f(x,y) dxdy+\int_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}  \log|x-x'|f(x,y)f(x',y') ~dx dy dx'dy'. $$

Any help would be much appriciated.

---

---

---

---

---

$\textbf{My attempt: }$
I tried using a logarithmic Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality (see eg https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.03667.pdf) but I dont think it will work because of the factor $h$ infront of the log. As you can tell the first term is close to the second moment of $f$, the second term is the Boltzman entropy of $f$, and the last term is a convolution. Note we can use the bound that for some $a\in(0,1),C\geq 0$

$$ \int f(x,y)\log f(x,y)\geq -C\Big(\int (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2 )f(x,y)+1 \Big)^a $$